# Is there a way to change views based off of Environment Variables in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, view, environment-variables, swiftui

I want to be able to change a view in SwiftUI with the tap of a button. I have buttons setup to toggle the environmental variables as follows

```
struct SettingsButton: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.settings.settingsView.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 25))
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                }
                .offset(x: 180, y: -372)}
        }
```

I've also declared the Observable object here

```
import Foundation
import GoogleSignIn

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var studentID = ""
    @Published var givenName = ""
    @Published var settingsView = false
    @Published var profileView = false
    @Published var isLogged = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser
}
```

And finally I have a ViewBuilder setup in the view that is loaded on start to listen for a change in the variable and to switch views accordingly, however when the app is loaded and the button is tapped the app freezes and remains unresponsive.

```
struct Login: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

    @ViewBuilder var body : some View {

        if settings.isLogged != nil {
            MainView()
        }
        else {
            LoginPage()
        }
        if settings.settingsView {
            SettingsView()
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is any known way to attempt this without the use of `.sheet` or Navigation Links any help with be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your `MainView(), LoginPage() and SettingsView()` I think you should be doing something like this in your `Login()` view:

I added `VStack` around your views:

```
struct Login: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

    @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if settings.isLogged != nil {
                MainView()
            } else {
                LoginPage()
            }
            if settings.settingsView {
                SettingsView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also ensure that you have the following in your `SceneDelegate` since your `UserSettings()` is defined as an `EnvironmentObject`:

```
// Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
let contentView = Login()
    .environmentObject(UserSettings())
```

Comment: The VStack prevented it from becoming nonresponsive, however it just stacks the views rather than replacing the previous one

Comment: @SeanOplinger That's totally based on your conditions though.